# Loop not functioning correctly

Tags: python, loops, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

Working with data frames and this is the code I have for it.

```
numbers = 3
count=0
A = 0
B = 0 
C = 0
for x in range(numbers):
    if str(data.iloc[count])== 'A':
        A += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[count])== 'B':
        B += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[count])== 'C':
        C += 1 
count +=1
#this is to return the count to check if it works
print A
print B
print C
```

but for some reason when I run this code only the count for A increases.

i.e. if the data in the index had a 'A', 'B', 'B' its still returning A = 3 and B = 0  where it should be returning A = 1, B = 2, and C = 0

what am I doing wrong? thanks again.

Comment: `count += 1` is probably intended to be indented.

Comment: Are you sure `data` is a DataFrame and not a Series?  I'm not sure how A could ever get to 1, much less 3.

Comment: yes because with the str(raw_input)) i set it as data = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns=columns)

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use `x`?

Comment: can you post your dataframe?

Comment: @DSM Because `data.iloc[count]` remains at `data.iloc[0]` and it iterates through the loop 3 times since `numbers=3`

Comment: @A.Kot: A should only increase if the corresponding `if` branch is taken.  But if data is a dataframe, then `str(data.iloc[count])` should look something like  `'x    1\nName: 0, dtype: int64'`.

Comment: @DSM Lol yeah you right. I dunno how he did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `count += 1` is not within the for loop, count += 1 only runs once, after the for loop is complete. It needs to be indented. Alternatively, you do not need to use a count variable since x is already going through the range 0 to 3:

```
numbers = 3
A = 0
B = 0 
C = 0
for x in range(numbers):
    if str(data.iloc[x])== 'A':
        A += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[x])== 'B':
        B += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[x])== 'C':
        C += 1 

#this is to return the count to check if it works
print A
print B
print C
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked

```
count=0
numbers = 3
A = 0
B = 0 
C = 0
for x in range(numbers):
    count +=1
    if str(data.iloc[x])== 'A':
        A += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[x])== 'B':
        B += 1 
    elif str(data.iloc[x])== 'C':
        C += 1 

#this is to return the count to check if it works
print A
print B
print C
```